Doctrine : Boolean values mapped to numbers (POSTGRESQL)
I have problems with Doctrine inserting or updating boolean field. The sql request is build with number instead of boolean value.
Here is an exemple :
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                ->update('MyBundle:Message', 'message')
                ->set('message.read', 'true');

result :
UPDATE project.message SET read= 1 WHERE ID = ?' with params ["225"]
ERROR: column "read" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
ty
Note : Message class
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="READ", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $read = false;

Note2 : to make it run, I can write :
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
->update('MyBundle:Message', 'message')
->set('message.read', 'true');
(like a string)
Is there a nicer way that can allow me to use boolean value on PHP side ?

Found the solution. Never use the boolean value directly but via setParameter.
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->update('MyBundle:Message', 'message')
            ->set('message.read', ':read')
            ->setParameter('read', true);

